# Angular reactive form value is including FormGroup data?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular form which I build dynamically within my application. When I try and view the value of the form, it appears to be including `FormGroups` and not the actual values of the form.

**Component 1:**

```
this.intakeForm = this.fb.group({
   requestor: ['', Validators.required],
   requestJustification: ['']
});
```

**Component 2:**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.intakeForm.addControl('tasks', new FormArray([]));
}

  /**
   * Create a new task based on the user/tool combination
   * @param user 
   * @param tool 
   */
  generateTask(user, tool) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'];
    control.push(this.newTaskControl(user, tool))
  }

  /**
   * Create a new control for this task
   * @param user 
   * @param tool 
   */
  newTaskControl(user, tool) {
    return this.fb.group({
      User: user,
      Tool: tool,
      Roles: [[]]
    })    
  }
```

**Component 3:**

```
someMethod(){
this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'].value[i].Roles.push(this.newRoleControl($event));
}


/**
 * Create a new control for role
 * @param user 
 * @param tool 
 */
  newRoleControl(role) {
    return this.fb.group({
      Role: role,
      Action: null
    })
  }
```

All these seems to be working fine but I was under the impression that when I get the forms value `intakeForm.value` that I would receive a JSON object of the data.

From what I can tell in the image below though, the form value is still including the `FormGroups`.

Is this normal? Shouldn't the whole value be a valid JSON string and not contain the form components it self?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are adding FormGroups as values to the "tasks" control, which should actually be instantiated as a FormGroup itself (instead of as a Control)

Comment: @Brian do you have an example of how this should be done by chance?

Comment: Here's a quick example: https://plnkr.co/edit/bsgDa8y0TCtvpjt9vIoR?p=preview

Comment: `this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'].value[i]` instead of `value[i]`, you need to take `controls[i]` to push the new Control to it

Comment: @ChauTran "[ts] Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'." Was this what you were suggesting?  `this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'].controls[i].Roles.push(this.newRoleControl($event));` ?

Comment: You can do something like this: `this.intakeForm.addControl('tasks', new FormGroup({});`,
`this.intakeForm.controls.tasks.addControl(role, this.newRoleControl(role))`

Comment: Okay, I will give this a shot. Just to be clear, the array `this.intakeForm.addControl('tasks', new FormArray([]));` can stay as is right, since I will be adding multiple controls to it?

Comment: @SBB https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarraything I made this for something else but just added an example that might help you (`somethingElse` in the stackblitz example). Try hitting the submit button and check your log